# Upload file from VueJS app to API in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http, vue.js, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to upload a file (Excel sheet) from a front-end app build with VueJS to an API build with Laravel 5.5. I've some form request validation which says to me that `The file field is required`. So the file doesn't get uploaded to my API at all.

VueJS file upload:

```
onFileChange(e) {
  let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

  if (files.length <= 0) {
    return;
  }

  this.upload(files[0]);
},
upload(file) {
  this.form.file = file;

  this.form.put('courses/import')
    .then((response) => {
      alert('Your upload has been started. This can take some time.');
    })
    .catch((response) => {
      alert('Something went wrong with your upload.');
    });
}
```

`this.form` is a Form class copied from [this project](https://github.com/laracasts/Vue-Forms/blob/master/public/js/app.js#L67) but the `data()` method returns a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object instead of a object.

`data()` method:

```
data() {
    let data = new FormData();

    for (let property in this.originalData) {
        data.append(property, this[property]);
    }

    return data;
}
```

The route:

[image]

FormRequest rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'file' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

If I look to the Network tab in Chrome DevTools it does seem that the request is send correctly: [(image after click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG9N8.png).

I've tried a lot of things, like sending the excel as base64 to the api. But then I couldn't decode it correctly. So now I'm trying this, but I can't solve the problem.

**Edit (controller function)**

```
public function update(ImportRequest $request, CoursesImport $file)
{
    $courses = $file->handleImport();

    dispatch(new StartCourseUploading($courses, currentUser()));

    $file->delete();

    return ok();
}
```

Comment: can you share your controller where you handle request ?

Comment: I edited my question. Personally I'm not sure if the problem is within the controller method. Because the form validation fails in the `ImportRequest`. So the code inside the method never gets executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `422` as status, I hope you aware of this meaning as *validation failed* according to your *Responses class*'s rule.

In laravel, PUT method won't accept file uploads, so you need to change from PUT to POST.

```
this.form.post('courses/import')
    .then((response) => {
      alert('Your upload has been started. This can take some time.');
    })
    .catch((response) => {
      alert('Something went wrong with your upload.');
    });
```

**Don't forget to update your routes of laravel**.

Other considerations:

1. Make sure you added property kind of following code

   ```
   data: {
       form: new Form({
           file:null
       })
   },
   ```
2. Check browser request weather sending form data properly or not , I added sample screen shot [image: Request]

My code samples

```js
class Errors {
  /**
   * Create a new Errors instance.
   */
  constructor() {
    this.errors = {};
  }


  /**
   * Determine if an errors exists for the given field.
   *
   * @param {string} field
   */
  has(field) {
    return this.errors.hasOwnProperty(field);
  }


  /**
   * Determine if we have any errors.
   */
  any() {
    return Object.keys(this.errors).length > 0;
  }


  /**
   * Retrieve the error message for a field.
   *
   * @param {string} field
   */
  get(field) {
    if (this.errors[field]) {
      return this.errors[field][0];
    }
  }


  /**
   * Record the new errors.
   *
   * @param {object} errors
   */
  record(errors) {
    this.errors = errors;
  }


  /**
   * Clear one or all error fields.
   *
   * @param {string|null} field
   */
  clear(field) {
    if (field) {
      delete this.errors[field];

      return;
    }

    this.errors = {};
  }
}


class Form {
  /**
   * Create a new Form instance.
   *
   * @param {object} data
   */
  constructor(data) {
    this.originalData = data;

    for (let field in data) {
      this[field] = data[field];
    }

    this.errors = new Errors();
  }


  /**
   * Fetch all relevant data for the form.
   */
  data() {
    let data = new FormData();

    for (let property in this.originalData) {
      data.append(property, this[property]);
    }

    return data;
  }


  /**
   * Reset the form fields.
   */
  reset() {
    for (let field in this.originalData) {
      this[field] = '';
    }

    this.errors.clear();
  }


  /**
   * Send a POST request to the given URL.
   * .
   * @param {string} url
   */
  post(url) {
    return this.submit('post', url);
  }


  /**
   * Send a PUT request to the given URL.
   * .
   * @param {string} url
   */
  put(url) {
    return this.submit('put', url);
  }


  /**
   * Send a PATCH request to the given URL.
   * .
   * @param {string} url
   */
  patch(url) {
    return this.submit('patch', url);
  }


  /**
   * Send a DELETE request to the given URL.
   * .
   * @param {string} url
   */
  delete(url) {
    return this.submit('delete', url);
  }


  /**
   * Submit the form.
   *
   * @param {string} requestType
   * @param {string} url
   */
  submit(requestType, url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios[requestType](url, this.data())
        .then(response => {
          this.onSuccess(response.data);

          resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.onFail(error.response.data);

          reject(error.response.data);
        });
    });
  }


  /**
   * Handle a successful form submission.
   *
   * @param {object} data
   */
  onSuccess(data) {
    alert(data.message); // temporary

    this.reset();
  }


  /**
   * Handle a failed form submission.
   *
   * @param {object} errors
   */
  onFail(errors) {
    this.errors.record(errors);
  }
}


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    form: new Form({
      file: ''
    })
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.form.post('/projects')
        .then(response => alert('Wahoo!'));
    },
    onFileChange(e) {
      let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

      if (files.length <= 0) {
        return;
      }

      this.upload(files[0]);
    },
    upload(file) {
      this.form.file = file;

      this.form.post('courses/import')
        .then((response) => {
          alert('Your upload has been started. This can take some time.');
        })
        .catch((response) => {
          alert('Something went wrong with your upload.');
        });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.2.3/css/bulma.css">
  <style>
    body {
      padding-top: 40px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app" class="container">


    <form method="POST" action="/projects" @submit.prevent="onSubmit" @keydown="form.errors.clear($event.target.name)">

      <input type="file" name="image" @change="onFileChange">
        
      <div class="control">
        <button class="button is-primary" :disabled="form.errors.any()">Create</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.15.3/axios.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.6/dist/vue.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Related Links**

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17560

Comment: Please  you add your `data` method

Comment: I added the `data()` method.

Comment: I didn't know the PUT method won't accept files. That was the problem. Changed to POST and everything worked just fine. Learn something everyday :), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you store your data in an associative array like data:

```
var formData = new FormData();
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key, index){
    if(Array.isArray(data[key])){
        formData.append(key + '[]', data[key]);
    } else {
        formData.append(key, data[key]);
    }
});
formData.append('file', document.getElementById('file_id').files[0]);
axios.post('path', formData).then( res => {
    console.log(res);
}).catch(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```